# Is it possible to size a gridview's columns if the gridview is dynamically bound?

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding

I'm using C# and ASP.NET, I've got the following on the ASP page:

```
<div id="divGrid" style='position:absolute; width:920px; height:400px; overflow:auto'>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Reports" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
    Width="1300px"
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView_Reports_SelectedIndexChanged"
    onrowdatabound="GridView_Reports_RowDataBound"
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

In the code-behind, I have this code snippet:

```
  //Now open the View and bind it to the GridView
  string SelectView = "SELECT * FROM " + MySQLView + "";
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str2);
  SqlCommand SelectCmd = new SqlCommand(SelectView, con);
  SqlDataAdapter SelectAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCmd);

  //Fill the dataset
  DataSet RunReport = new DataSet();
  SelectAdapter.Fill(RunReport);

  GridView_Reports.DataSource = RunReport;
  GridView_Reports.DataBind();
```

So, as you can see, the dataset is created dynamically.  I do this because there are several possible reports and I wanted to make it as generic as possible.

It seems, from my googling, that a gridview doesn't actually have columns when it's done dynamically.  In that, the following line of code will always return 0:

```
int columnscount = GridView_Reports.Columns.Count;
```

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to loop through all columns and set their width dynamically.  Hard-coding this isn't an option; the entire form is table-driven so that adding a new report is as easy as adding info to a table, and I'm not going to hard-code column info for 20+ reports.  The Rows.Count works fine, there must be a way to loop through the columns somehow and set their widths?  Even if I could just get their widths to all be the same size I'd be OK with that, I just need to be able to specify that size!

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head (not on usual machine) the exact details but yes you can dynamically size. You need to do it on DataBind/DataBound (something like that) event though and catch the row / column creation at that point. If you don't get any answers I will dig up some sample code I wrote about a year ago that did exactly what you are describing here.

Comment: @Belogix - If you could dig up that sample code, I'd appreciate it.  Still no luck getting this to work.

Comment: If you still need it I will try and find this evening (11 hours time).

Comment: @Belogix - Yes, please!

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but might be worth a try. Alternatively, could you not call a separate method to do this post DataBinding.

In DataGrid:

```
OnItemDataBound="dgMyGrid_ItemBound"
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void dgMyGrid_ItemBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            e.Item.Cells["MyCol"].CssClass = "MyCssClass";
        }
}
```

EDIT:

Apologies, not read your question properly. Your using a DataGridView not a DataGrid. Trying looking at this: [fix a columns width when a list is bound to a datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465770/fix-a-columns-width-when-a-list-is-bound-to-a-datagridview)

Comment: I changed the name slightly, but I don't think it likes the code as it's written.  It's throwing an error: "No overload for 'GridView_Reports_SizeColumns' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'".  I think it only likes (object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Try the new code. I've chosen to use a Css class for this, in which I also specified the width.

Comment: The link provided is for a windows form.  I'm using a web form (using System.Web.UI.WebControls;) and the DataBindingComplete method isn't available to me.  I tried using OnDataBound but that's not working either.  Here's what's available to me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you try OnItemDataBound?